# Changing elements in an array using an apply function in r

Tags: arrays, r, loops, apply, sapply

So at the moment, I have an array with 8 columns and rows refer to people. I want to change the value of one column to 1 or 0 based on the value of another column for that person using an apply function.

I already have this with a loop, which is

```
for(i in 1:nrow(OutComes)) {
  if(OutComes[i,"Risk_Factor"] > 0.7) {
    OutComes[i,"OnsetAge"] = 1 
  } else {
    OutComes[i,"OnsetAge"] = 0 
  }
}
```

So the OutCome array has a vector called "Risk_Factor" where each person is assigned a uniform random number using `runif()`. If this number is greater than 0.7, an element along the same row in the column "Onset Age" changes.

How would this work with an apply function?
I have searched but can't find anything which helps.

Comment: See this link, might it helps [link](http://petewerner.blogspot.in/2012/12/using-apply-sapply-lapply-in-r.html)

Answer (score 1):

Assignment is a vectorized function, so there's no need for a loop.

```
is_risky <- OutComes[,"Risk_Factor"] > 0.7
OutComes[, "OnsetAge"] <- as.integer(is_risky)
```